# Multiple cells got affected after calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView, and I want to change text color of the selected row. But I see every other 15 row got affected along with the one I clicked. This is tested under the master-detail sample project.

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(){ 
    self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

I checked cellForRowAtIndexPath value in debug session, it seems returning only one object, how come other cells got affected too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are reused - almost certainly you are not resetting your cells to a base state in `prepareForReuse` and configuring them correctly on each call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

When you look at a table view that can display some number of cells at once, typically there will only exist one more cell than can be shown. When a cell is moved off the screen it is placed in a pool of cells for reuse. Just before a cell moves onto the screen it is configured by you, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If you have configured something in the cell and you do not configure that explicitly every time you return a cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then that configuration persists in the cell that is in the reuse pool. The function `prepareForReuse` is also called before each cell is reused - if you have subclassed `UITableViewCell` then you can implement this function to return the cell to a base configuration, so that settings like text color do not unexpectedly affect multiple cells.

This approach makes it possible to scroll through an entire table view smoothly with a minimum amount of memory used. It is an expensive operation to create and destroy cells every time one disappears and a new one is required.

The simplest fix is to always set the text color in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - either to the base color or to the special color you want in some cells.